# Not able to get a Database instance inside a Model class

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, singleton

Does a class' __construct() method need to be public, in order to call a static method of this class inside of another class?

I'm trying to get a Database instance inside my Model class (MVC app), by calling a static method of the Database class. The constructor of this Database class is private, in order to have a singleton pattern. But it seems to be interfering when I try to call the static method inside my Model class.

When I set the Database constructor to public, it works. But then it's not really a singleton pattern anymore.

Any suggestions?

**Database class:**

```
class Database extends PDO {

    private static $instance;
    private $dsn;
    private $user;
    private $pass;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dsn  = DB_ENGINE .':host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME;
        $this->user = DB_USER;
        $this->pass = DB_PASS;
        parent::__construct($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->pass);
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $object;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * select
     * @param string $sql An SQL string
     * @param array $array Paramters to bind
     * @param constant $fetchMode A PDO Fetch mode
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function select($sql, $fetchMode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, $array = array())
    {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue("$key", $value);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll($fetchMode);
    }

    /**
     * insert
     * @param string $table A name of table to insert into
     * @param string $data An associative array
     */
    public function insert($table, $data)
    {
        ksort($data);

        $fieldNames = implode(', ', array_keys($data));
        $fieldValues = ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($data));

        $stmt = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($fieldNames) VALUES ($fieldValues)");

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
    }

    /**
     * update
     * @param string $table A name of table to insert into
     * @param string $data An associative array
     * @param string $where the WHERE query part
     */
    public function update($table, $data, $where)
    {
        ksort($data);

        $fieldDetails = NULL;
        foreach ($data as $key=> $value) {
            $fieldDetails .= "$key=:$key,";
        }
        $fieldDetails = rtrim($fieldDetails, ',');

        $stmt = $this->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $fieldDetails WHERE $where");

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
    }

    /**
     * delete
     * 
     * @param string $table
     * @param string $where
     * @param integer $limit
     * @return integer Affected Rows
     */
    public function delete($table, $where, $limit = 1)
    {
        return $this->exec("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $where LIMIT $limit");
    }

}
```

**Model class:**

```
class Model {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = Database::getInstance();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should be getting an error message, your code is invalid. You can't have a private constructor on a class that's inheriting a class with a public constructor, and PDO's constructor is public. Also, why would you want to make this a singleton in the first place?

Comment: Indeed, I get a blank page using this. And I very much like the idea of being sure to only have one database connection. But I guess if I make a new Database object inside my Model class, it doesn't matter, right?

Comment: A blank page? Oh my, you have [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) off, you should always have it on during development. Your code generates a fatal error that's rather descriptive, you would have immediately known what's the problem if you had seen the error. Also, set [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) to `E_ALL` while you're at it.

Comment: Wow, shame on me. Thanks for reminding me. So it's sufficient enough to just make a new Database object inside my Model class?

Comment: If you want to keep inheriting from PDO (which would mean no singleton), then you could simply pass the Database instance to the model as a parameter in its constructor. If you go with the singleton, then your model stays as is, but you'd have to create a PDO instance in Database's constructor (and write adapter methods for every PDO method you want available to Database, as you won't be inheriting it anymore).

Comment: Sidenote, requiring a subclass to have a public constructor sounds dumb. But I do agree that making the Database class an adapter would make more sense. Also, if data libraries in PHP work anything like other languages/frameworks, you don't want your Database object to be a singleton. The framework should handle connection pooling and the like for you.

Comment: I've updated my Database class with the necessary adapter methods. Thanks for your input, Mike!

Comment: If you have the solution, then you should post that as an answer and accept it. Others with the same problem don't know otherwise how to solve it.